# Write 100 million files to s3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-emr, emr

My main aim is to split out records into files according to the ids of each record, and there are over 15 billion records right now which can certainly increase. I need a scalable solution using Amazon EMR. I have already got this done for a smaller dataset having around 900 million records.

Input files are in csv format, with one of the field which is need to be the file name in the output.
So say that there are following input records:

```
awesomeId1, somedetail1, somedetail2
awesomeID1, somedetail3, somedetail4
awesomeID2, somedetail5, somedetail6
```

So now 2 files should be as output, one named `awesomeID1.dat` and other as `awesomeID2.dat`, each having records pertaining to respective IDs.

Size of the input: Total 600 GB (size of gzippef files) per month, each files is around 2 3 GB. And I need to process it for around 6 months or more at a time. so Total data size would be 6*600 GB (compressed).

Previously I was getting `Too many open files` error when I was using `FileByKeyTextOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat<Text, Text>` to write to s3 according to the id value. Then as I have explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953251/too-many-open-files-in-emr), instead of writing every file directly to s3, I wrote them locally and moved to s3 in batches of 1024 files.

But now with increased amount of data, I am getting following message from s3 and then it skips writing the file in question : `"Please reduce your request rate."` Also I am having to run on a cluster with 200 m1.xlarge machines which then take around 2 hours, and hence it is very costly too!

I would like to have a **scalable** solution which shall not fail if amount of data increases again in future.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some info on SlowDown errors: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=89722#89816 You should insert into S3 in alphabetical order. Also the limit is dynamic and re-adjusts over time, so slow down and try to increase your rate later.

Perhaps you are better off using a database than a filesystem? How big is the total dataset?

DynamoDB may be a good fit, but may be expensive at $1/GB/month. (Since it uses SSD for backing storage.)

RDS is another option. Its pricing is from $0.10/GB/month.

Even better may be to host your own NoSQL or other datastore on EC2, such as on the new hs1.8xlarge instance. You can launch it only when you need it, and back it up to S3 when you don't.

Comment: It then again need to be consumed by another Hadoop process and we are trying to keep everything on s3. The dataset is actually logs and are of size 600GB gzipped, per month and we have to process more than 6 months data at once!

Comment: DynamoDB is way too slow on insertions and I do not think it is a good alternative here.

Comment: How about downloading the gzip'd file (or a piece thereof) to each node and using instance storage? The High I/O instances have both 2TB of SSD and a 10Gbit/s link to get the file from S3.

Comment: It needs to be processed! Output of a hadoop mapreduce job is 100 million files and that needs to be written to s3.

Comment: And there is not one file of 600 GB gzipped there are multiple files. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please update your question with the specifics of how many files of what size, what needs to be read, written, etc.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear there. around 15 billion input records are there and after processing them I need to output some 100 million files. Nevertheless I will add more clarity.

Comment: what size are these records and files? if you give more info, we can suggest alternate (better!) solutions.

Comment: S3 is not the be-all end-all. It has its limits and it has things it was optimized for and things it was not. Another idea is to set up your own storage nodes on EC2 that are an intermediary between large objects on S3 and small objects used in your process. hs1.8xlarge is a new beast that could perhaps fill this role. There are various software you can use on them, like a NoSQL database or a roll-your-own Java REST server.

Comment: This process isn't something wherein we need to access the data daily few times, but just few times per month. Also the same process needs to be run over a diverse set of data, which means each time on a different data. So having a storage node would perhaps be more costly. But if we do not get anything else then I would try this for sure.

Comment: The storage node can use S3 for backing storage (with large gzip files, for example) and be launched only when needed. Also, see my updated answer on SlowDown errors.