# EMR Hadoop processing whole S3 file

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, emr, amazon-emr

I have a bunch of small (1KB to 1MB) text files stored in Amazon S3 that I would like to process using Amazon EMR's Hadoop.

Each record given to the mapper needs to contain the entire contents of a text file as well as some way to determine the filename, so I cannot use the default TextInputFormat.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Is there anything else I can do (like copying files from S3 to hdfs) to increase performance?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Please refer following questions.

- [s3fs on Amazon EMR: Will it scale for approx 100million small files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342160/s3fs-on-amazon-emr-will-it-scale-for-approx-100million-small-files?rq=1)
- [Write 100 million files to s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081123/write-100-million-files-to-s3)
- [Too many open files in EMR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953251/too-many-open-files-in-emr)

If you don't have any large files, but have a lot of files, it's sufficient to use `s3cmd get --recursive s3://<url> .` command. After retrieved files into EMR instance, you could create tables with Hive. For example, you can load whole files with `LOAD DATA` statement with partition.

**sample**

This is a sample code

```
#!/bin/bash

s3cmd get --recursive s3://your.s3.name .

# create table with partitions
hive -e "SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=true; DROP TABLE IF EXISTS import_s3_data;"
hive -e "CREATE TABLE import_s3_data( rawdata string )
         PARTITIONED BY (tier1 string, tier2, string, tier3 string);"

LOAD_SQL=""

# collect files as array
FILES=(`find . -name \*.txt -print`)

for FILE in ${FILES[@]}
do
    DIR_INFO=(`echo ${FILE##./} | tr -s '/' ' '`)
    T1=${DIR_INFO[0]}
    T2=${DIR_INFO[1]}
    T3=${DIR_INFO[2]}
    LOAD_SQL="${LOAD_SQL} LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '${FILE}' INTO TABLE
              import_s3_data PARTITION (tier1 = '${T1}', tier2 = '${T2}', tier3 = '${T3}');"
done
hive -e "${LOAD_SQL}"
```

**another option**

I think there are some another options to retrieve small S3 data

- [S3DistCp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html) ... it will merge small file as large one in order to deal with Hadoop
- [Hive - External Tables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables) ... it will create an external table referring s3 storages. However, it has almost same performance compared with the case to use `s3cmd get`. It might more effective in such a case, there are many large raw or gziped files on S3.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach according to me would be to create an `external table` on the CSV files and load it into another table stored again in `S3` bucket in `parquet` format. You will not have to write any script in that case, just few SQL queries.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE databasename.CSV_EXT_Module( 
recordType BIGINT, 
servedIMSI BIGINT, 
ggsnAddress STRING, 
chargingID BIGINT, 
...
...
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LOCATION 's3://module/input/csv_files/' 
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

The above table will only be an external table mapped to the csv file.

Create another table on top of it if you want the query to run faster:

```
CREATE TABLE databasename.RAW_Module as
SELECT  
recordType, 
servedIMSI, 
ggsnAddress, 
chargingID,
...
regexp_extract(INPUT__FILE__NAME,'(.*)/(.*)',2) as filename from 
databasename.CSV_EXT_Module
STORED AS PARQUET 
LOCATION 's3://module/raw/parquet_files/';
```

Change the regexp_extract to have the required input file name.