# Too many open files in spark aborting spark job

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2, amazon-emr

In my application i am reading 40 GB text files that is totally spread across 188 files .
I split this files and create xml files per line in spark using pair rdd .
For 40 GB of input it will create many millions small xml files and this is my requirement.
All working fine but when spark saves files in S3 it throws error and job fails .

Here is the exception i get

> Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException:
>   /mnt/s3/emrfs-2408623010549537848/0000000000: Too many open files     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
>     at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)   at
>   java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:632)    at
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.files.TemporaryFiles.create(TemporaryFiles.java:70)
>     at
>   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream.openNewPart(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:493)
>     ... 21 more
>
> ApplicationMaster host: 10.97.57.198    ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
>      queue: default      start time: 1542344243252   final status: FAILED
>   tracking URL:
>   http://ip-10-97-57-234.tr-fr-nonprod.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:20888/proxy/application_1542343091900_0001/
>      user: hadoop Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application
>   application_1542343091900_0001 finished with failed status

And this as well

> com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception:
>   Please reduce your request rate. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code:
>   503; Error Code: SlowDown; Request ID: D33581CA9A799F64; S3 Extended
>   Request ID:
>   /SlEplo+lCKQRVVH+zHiop0oh8q8WqwnNykK3Ga6/VM2HENl/eKizbd1rg4vZD1BZIpp8lk6zwA=),
>   S3 Extended Request ID:
>   /SlEplo+lCKQRVVH+zHiop0oh8q8WqwnNykK3Ga6/VM2HENl/eKizbd1rg4vZD1BZIpp8lk6zwA=

Here is my code to do that .

```
object TestAudit {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {


    val inputPath = args(0)
    val output = args(1)
    val noOfHashPartitioner = args(2).toInt

    //val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AuditXML").setMaster("local");
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AuditXML")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
    val input = sc.textFile(inputPath)


    val pairedRDD = input.map(row => {
      val split = row.split("\\|")
      val fileName = split(0)
      val fileContent = split(1)
      (fileName, fileContent)
    })

    import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable
    import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat

    class RddMultiTextOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat[Any, Any] {
      override def generateActualKey(key: Any, value: Any): Any = NullWritable.get()
      override def generateFileNameForKeyValue(key: Any, value: Any, name: String): String = key.asInstanceOf[String]
    }

    pairedRDD.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(10000)).saveAsHadoopFile("s3://a205381-tr-fr-development-us-east-1-trf-auditabilty//AUDITOUTPUT", classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[RddMultiTextOutputFormat], classOf[GzipCodec])

  }

}
```

Even i tried reducing no of HashPartitioner then also it does not work

Comment: The error is most likely coming from your last line of code when it's trying to save the result. Try to reduce the number of partitions parameter in `new HashPartitioner(10000)`.

Comment: @dk-na but will it not impact the performance ?

Comment: @Sudarshan: your current job is failing, and being throttled by AWS too. Worry about "working" before "performant"

Comment: @SteveLoughran it works if i use only two files with total size 2 GB as input which creates 4 millions files

Answer (score 1):

Every process on Unix systems has a limitation of open files or number of file descriptors. As your data is large and partitions to subfile (in internal of Spark), your process meet the limitation and error.
You can increase the *number of file descriptors* for each user as following:

edit the file: */etc/security/limits.conf* and add (or modify)

```
*         hard    nofile      500000
*         soft    nofile      500000
root      hard    nofile      500000
root      soft    nofile      500000
```

This will set the *nofile* (number of file descriptors) feature to *500000* for each user along with the root user.

After restarting the changes will be applied.

Also, someone can set the number of file descriptors for a special process, by setting the *LimitNOFILE*. For example, if you use yarn to run Spark jobs and the Yarn daemon will be started using *systemd*, you can add LimitNOFILE=128000 to Yarn systemd script(resource manager and nodemanager) to set Yarn process number of file descriptors to *128000*.

related articles:

- [3 Methods to Change the Number of Open File Limit in Linux](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/03-methods-change-number-open-file-limit-linux/)
- [Limits on the number of file descriptors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84227/limits-on-the-number-of-file-descriptors)

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation ..But as you know i am using EMR cluster which is transient.So how can i set this into EMR ..Do i have to set this in Master node or in the booths tarp Action ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953251/too-many-open-files-in-emr

Comment: I just tried based on the link you have suggested but my BootStrap is failing `bootstrap action 1 returned a non-zero return code` ..I just created .sh file in S3 and copy pasted the script mentioned ...Any idea why it is failing ?

Comment: I have changed the value but still i am getting same issue ..This time like reduce your request rate and if i use more than 2 GB file i get too many open file issue