# How to create an XML file per line in Java AWS lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, file-handling

I have a file of size 1GB that looks like this:

```
1_107570678_ANA_2C68EF2F-AB17-40EF-9095-387DE1D5D745_App.xml|<CAudit><ai2aiinst nT="LevFcf#A0" auNdSTy="Analytics" auNdTy="Identifier" ndNo="1" aId="1" conDes="Levered Free Cash Flow" conCd="LevFcf" aiaGUId="1_107570678_ANA_2C68EF2F-AB17-40EF-9095-387DE1D5D745" aiaId="1" aiKey="2990569588" aiId="14" pEndDt="2013-Dec-31" perCd="A" isYr2Dt="False" ><AudNode aId="1" ndNo="2" auNdTy="Operation" auNdSTy="-" nV="2626287569.000000000000000" ><AudNode aId="1" ndNo="3" auNdTy="Operation" auNdSTy="-" nV="2825849069.000000000000000" ><AudNode aId="1" ndNo="4" auNdTy="Identifier" auNdSTy="Standardized" nT="STD.SEBITDA#A0" nV="3130019939.000000000000000" ><ai2si nV="3130019939.00000" nT="STD.SEBITDA#A0" auNdSTy="Standardized" auNdTy="Identifier" ndNo="4" aId="1" inId="1035" conDes="Earnings before Interest, Taxes, Depreciation &amp; Amortization (EBITDA)" conCd="SEBITDA" stdaGUId="841_107570667_STD_2C68EF2F-AB17-40EF-9095-387DE1D5D745" stdIaId="841" siKey="12004131416271429" siId="413" sLiCurIso="KRW" sCurIso="KRW" stCurIso="KRW" stTyCd="INC" sId="1" pEndDt="2013-Dec-31" pId="2" fId="192730348494" fbId="1" /></AudNode><AudNode aId="1" ndNo="5" auNdTy="Identifier" auNdSTy="Standardized" nT="STD.STAX#A0" nV="304170870.000000000000000" ><ai2si nV="304170870.00000" nT="STD.STAX#A0" auNdSTy="Standardized" auNdTy="Identifier" ndNo="5" aId="1" inId="968" conDes="Income Taxes" conCd="STAX" stdaGUId="807_107570667_STD_2C68EF2F-AB17-40EF-9095-387DE1D5D745" stdIaId="807" siKey="120038112041962629" siId="381" sLiCurIso="KRW" sCurIso="KRW" stCurIso="KRW" stTyCd="INC" sId="1" pEndDt="2013-Dec-31" pId="2" fId="192730348494" fbId="1" /></AudNode></AudNode><AudNode aId="1" ndNo="6" auNdTy="Operation" auNdSTy="SUM" nV="199561500.000000000000000" ><AudNode aId="1" ndNo="7" auNdTy="Identifier" auNdSTy="Standardized" nT="STD.SCEX#A0" nV="199561500.000000000000000" ><ai2si nV="199561500.00000" nT="STD.SCEX#A0" auNdSTy="Standardized" auNdTy="Identifier" ndNo="7" aId="1" inId="888" conDes="Capital Expenditures - Total" conCd="SCEX" stdaGUId="704_107570667_STD_2C68EF2F-AB17-40EF-9095-387DE1D5D745" stdIaId="704" siKey="12002771860094347" siId="277" sLiCurIso="KRW" sCurIso="KRW" stCurIso="KRW" stTyCd="CAS" sId="1" pEndDt="2013-Dec-31" pId="2" fId="192730348494" fbId="1" /></AudNode><AudNode aId="1" ndNo="8" auNdTy="Constant" nV="0.000000000000000" /></AudNode></AudNode></ai2aiinst></CAudit>
3_107570678_ANA_2C68EF2F-AB17-40EF-9095-387DE1D5D745_App.xml|<CAudit><ai2aiinst nT="ExcessCashMargin#A0" auNdSTy="Analytics" auNdTy="Identifier" ndNo="1" aId="3" conDes="Excess Cash Margin - %" conCd="ExcessCashMargin" aiaGUId="3_107570678_ANA_2C68EF2F-AB17-40EF-9095-387DE1D5D745" aiaId="3" aiKey="2990569579" aiId="5" pEndDt="2013-Dec-31" perCd="A" isYr2Dt="False" ><AudNode aId="3" ndNo="2" auNdTy="Operation" auNdSTy="*" nV="2.257160458878393" ><AudNode aId="3" ndNo="8" auNdTy="Identifier" auNdSTy="PseudoFinancialConcept" nT="PERCENTSCALE#A0" nV="100.000000000000000" /><AudNode aId="3" ndNo="3" auNdTy="Operation" auNdSTy="//" nV="0.022571604588784" ><AudNode aId="3" ndNo="7" auNdTy="Identifier" auNdSTy="Standardized" nT="STD.STLR#A0" nV="68201182151.000000000000000" ><ai2si nV="68201182151.00000" nT="STD.STLR#A0" auNdSTy="Standardized" auNdTy="Identifier" ndNo="7" aId="3" inId="990" conDes="Revenue from Business Activities - Total" conCd="STLR" stdaGUId="813_107570667_STD_2C68EF2F-AB17-40EF-9095-387DE1D5D745" stdIaId="813" siKey="12003871970759396" siId="387" sLiCurIso="KRW" sCurIso="KRW" stCurIso="KRW" stTyCd="INC" sId="1" pEndDt="2013-Dec-31" pId="2" fId="192730348494" fbId="1" /></AudNode><AudNode aId="3" ndNo="4" auNdTy="Operation" auNdSTy="-" nV="1539410116.000000000000000" ><AudNode aId="3" ndNo="6" auNdTy="Identifier" auNdSTy="Standardized" nT="STD.SNIC#A0" nV="438846856.000000000000000" ><ai2si nV="438846856.00000" nT="STD.SNIC#A0" auNdSTy="Standardized" auNdTy="Identifier" ndNo="6" aId="3" inId="1055" conDes="Net Income after Minority Interest" conCd="SNIC" stdaGUId="856_107570667_STD_2C68EF2F-AB17-40EF-9095-387DE1D5D745" stdIaId="856" siKey="120043012135950005" siId="430" sLiCurIso="KRW" sCurIso="KRW" stCurIso="KRW" stTyCd="INC" sId="1" pEndDt="2013-Dec-31" pId="2" fId="192730348494" fbId="1" /></AudNode><AudNode aId="3" ndNo="5" auNdTy="Identifier" auNdSTy="Standardized" nT="STD.STLO#A0" nV="1978256972.000000000000000" ><ai2si nV="1978256972.00000" nT="STD.STLO#A0" auNdSTy="Standardized" auNdTy="Identifier" ndNo="5" aId="3" inId="924" conDes="Net Cash Flow from Operating Activities" conCd="STLO" stdaGUId="719_107570667_STD_2C68EF2F-AB17-40EF-9095-387DE1D5D745" stdIaId="719" siKey="12002951348701451" siId="295" sLiCurIso="KRW" sCurIso="KRW" stCurIso="KRW" stTyCd="CAS" sId="1" pEndDt="2013-Dec-31" pId="2" fId="192730348494" fbId="1" /></AudNode></AudNode></AudNode></AudNode></ai2aiinst></CAudit>
```

I need to read this file and split it using `|`, and I need to create two files in the above case because it has two rows.

Name of the file will be left side of the delimiter and content will be right side of the delimiter.

Can some one help me writing java code for this which can read 1 GB file and write into S3 quickly - like within 5 seconds - because I will have a very huge number of such files coming in, like 10,000 in a day.

Currently I am doing this in EMR but I get too many open files issue, so I thought I can utilize AWS lambda functionality which has increased memory and time.

I am doing this in SPARK/EMR where i am using pair RDD and create file name as key and file content as value .I am loading 10 GB of data 10 such files in EMR which will create 4 millions small xml files but it fails finally.
Here is such example 
[Too many open files in spark aborting spark job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331833/too-many-open-files-in-spark-aborting-spark-job/53337069?noredirect=1#comment93553630_53337069)

This is my code what i am doing as of now but it takes more time to create files

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class DataMaker {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
         DataMaker dm=new DataMaker();
         String file= "C:\\Users\\u6034690\\Desktop\\ONEFILE\\12482.txt";
         int temp=0;
         try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {

                    String[] output = line.split("\\|");
                    System.out.println(output[0]);
                    System.out.println(output[1]);

                    ++temp;
                    if(temp<4000000){ //may be i need some changes here
                     dm.filewriter(output[1]+" "+temp+")","C:\\Users\\u6034690\\Desktop\\ONEFILE\\"+output[0]);
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
     }
     void filewriter(String linetoline,String filename) throws IOException{
         BufferedWriter fbw =null;
         try{

             OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                   new FileOutputStream(filename, true), "UTF-8");
              fbw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
             fbw.write(linetoline);
             fbw.newLine();

         }catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
         }
         finally {
             fbw.close();
            }
     }

    }
```

To create 70k files from a single it takes approx 10 minutes and i have 1 GB size of file

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "too many open files issue" on EMR? It's not clear to me that Lambda is going to be a clear winner here vs. EMR.

Comment: @jarmod i have updated my question with the EMR issue .